# Upgraded tensorflow to 2.1, now its broken

Tags: python, tensorflow

#### The problem

I upgraded tensorflow and afterwards I wanted to check so it still used my GPU. I used the command stated on their website to check if its either using the CPU or GPU. However, this command generated a error that I have not been able to understand.

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: I used a code example from: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available to check GPU
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Windows 10
- **Mobile device (e.g. iPhone 8, Pixel 2, Samsung Galaxy) if the issue happens on mobile device**: N/A
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: not sure, used pip install tensorflow.
- **TensorFlow version**: 2.1.0
- **Python version**: 3.7.3
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**: N/A
- **GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source)**: N/A
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: cuda_10.1.105_418.96_win10, cudnn: v7.6.5.32
- **GPU model and memory**: GTX 1060 6GB
- **Exact command to reproduce**:

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available(
    cuda_only=False,
    min_cuda_compute_capability=None
)
```

#### What I have done trying to solve the issue

I have reinstalled tensorflow with the following commands:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip --no-cache-dir install tensorflow
```

I have reinstalled Cuda, following the instructions on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

I have also tried reinstalling python including all packages. I have also tried downgrading to version 10.0 on cuda (which some recommended when I search for similar problems.

#### Source code / logs

```
#This is the command to repoduce the error
import tensorflow as tf

tf.test.is_gpu_available(
    cuda_only=False,
    min_cuda_compute_capability=None
)

#This is the error
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-18-dd35409f5a28>", line 3, in <module>
    tf.test.is_gpu_available(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'test'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2039, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-18-dd35409f5a28>", line 3, in <module>
    tf.test.is_gpu_available(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'test'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2039, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\users\jesper\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Can you try `pip uninstall tensorflow` and then `pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade tensorflow`? The problem could be that some dependencies are not correct. You can also try a virtual environment and install tensorflow and its dependencies there.

Comment: @Jakub Did not help, I'll try reinstall python.

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade from Tensorflow 1.x to 2.1, or from 2.0 to 2.1?

The reason for the error might be that **`Tensorflow GPU`** might not be installed properly.

Instructions are mentioned below:

**Remove CUDA**: Delete any previous CUDA version (use if you have any):

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda*
```

**Install CUDA**:

Add keys to download (so after apt-get update you got CUDA):

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub && echo "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
```

Install:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install cuda-10-1 cuda-drivers
```

**Make a reboot now. After add CUDA to path**:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}' >> ~/.bashrc && echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc && sudo ldconfig
```

**Install cuDNN**:
Download newest cuDNN release from here (require log in NVIDIA account). After that click Agree, select “Download cuDNN v7.6.5 (November 18th, 2019), for CUDA 10.1” and choose “cuDNN library for Linux”.

```
tar -xf cudnn-10.1-linux-x64-v7.6.5.32.tgz && sudo cp -R cuda/include/* /usr/local/cuda-10.1/include && sudo cp -R cuda/lib64/* /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
```

**Install libcupti**:
Installed libcupti-dev, added path from this library and reload bashrc:

```
sudo apt-get install libcupti-dev && echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc && sudo ldconfig
```

**Install Tensorflow**:

At the time when this article wrote, you might can’t install Tensorflow version 2.1.0, because this is only the first release candidate version. But update pip version and setuptools could help. But after update you might see that you will be disable to install any packages through pip anymore — if this happens, uninstall the newest pip version helps.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools && python3 -m pip install tensorflow==2.1.0rc0
# Only use if pip is broken:
python3 -m pip uninstall pip
```

**Check Tensorflow**:
Run a new terminal and check from python3 shell:

```
python3
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.test.is_gpu_available()) -> should return True
```

For more details, refer this [Medium Link](https://medium.com/@Oysiyl/install-tensorflow-2-with-gpu-support-on-ubuntu-19-10-f502ae85593c) and this [Tensorflow Page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answers. I however downgraded again and got it working. I might give your tips and recommendations whenever I get time again.

Comment: Note that I wrote Windows 10 as OS. apt -get commands will not work. However the structure of the instructions can still be replicated on windows. I have not had time to try this out yet.